# ¿Por qué IAppBuilder no contiene la definición del metodo MapSignalR?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, nuget

Hola estoy creando una aplicación que pretende ser en tiempo real sobre ASP.NET, Instale SignalR 2.2.2 mediante la consola nuGet:

```
install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

Pero al tratar de inicializar mediante la clase "startup" de Owin no se reconoce el método `MapSignalR()` que debería estar dentro de `IAppBuilder` aquí el código

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using MyWebApplication;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo me tira este error:

> Error  9   'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and no extension method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\brayanzavala\Desktop\BPM_BLU\Core\Global.asax.cs   18

Sé que el método`MapSignalR()` se encuentra en una extensión de para Owin y se aloja en `SignalR.core.dll`, traté de actualizar este último pero aún no he logrado hacerlo funcionar.

**EDIT:**

Intente instalar la versión 2.2.2 Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core mediante la consola con el comando:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core -Version 2.2.2
```

sin embargo me aparecen estos mensajes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando en realidad el dll de Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core sigue siendo la versión 1.1.0.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro mucho sentido a lo que pasa, estoy considerando buscar el dll directamente en Internet.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Intenta instalando  al proyecto: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost`  desde la consola de nuget y dinos que pasa.

Comment: @Einer, no cabe duda, eres uno de los maestros del C# y del .net :D ¡Muchas gracias por estar participando activamente con la hermandad de SOes!

Comment: @Einer, ya instale el OwinSelfHost pero aun así no funciona, muchas gracias por la respuesta seguiré intentando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que agregar instalar la última versión con la consola de nuget:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core -Version 2.2.2
```

Comment: Hola Einer, ya intente instalando el selfHost y lamentablemente no da resultados, gracias por el comentario

Comment: la actualizacion del SignalR.Core no ha funcionado, he editado la pregunta para ser un poco mas especifico

Comment: Tenia un dll muerto de SignalR.Core, lo elimine manualmente y después ejecute el comando que mencionaste anteriormente `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core -Version 2.2.2`, Edita tu respuesta y añade el comando para marcarla como correcta